# Ruby on rails regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I need to implement regular expression for matching a string   anywhere near the starting, ending and middle of a  text. That is if the query word is "Gabbar Singh" it should match "Gabbar" or "Gabbar Singh".  I implemented it using   % % symbol.Its working but its not working if "Gabbar Singh" occurs in the middle of a  word . for example if some text cantains "#GabbarSingh " , its not showing that particular result.

My line of code for controller.

```
@tweets = Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?", "%#{search_term}%")
```

My code for the view

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>

<ul>

  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>

  <li><%= tweets.tweet_source %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_sc_name %></li>
<li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
<li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>


<% end %>
</ul>
```

I want my results to match anything that has "Gabbar Singh" also in the middle of a string or a word. Anybody help me with this .

Comment: It looks like you want to implement some sort of full text search.  Have a look at some of the gems like Sunspot, Sphinx etc.

Comment: The db is MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: The Data Base is mysql

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

@tweets = Tweets.where("tweet_text ILIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")

Comment: ya tried that it did'nt work out

Comment: If you are looking to search something like this "#GabbarSingh " then it is better to use full-text searching than using % based likes.